# Case insensitive search with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I've used the script below to search through a table to display the results matching the user input. If you type in a capital 'K' and the desired result starts with a lower 'k', the result simply won't show as it does not match *exactly* the user input. How do I select the `.value()` case insensitive?

```
$("#search_input").keyup(function() {
  var value = this.value;
  $("#table").find(".table_row").each(function(index) {
    if (!index) return;
    var id = $(this).find(".table_cell").first().text();
    $(this).toggle(id.indexOf(value) !== -1);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of a script which you gave, compare strings as is. Its better to [lowercase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) user input and text id of table cell in order to compare both results and then toggle what you need.

```
$("#content").keyup(function() {
  var value = this.value.toLowerCase();
  $("#table").find(".table_row").each(function(index) {
    if (!index) return;
    var id = $(this).find(".table_cell").first().text();
    if (id.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) !== -1) {
      $(this).toggle();
    }
  });
});
```

And one more thing to add. Just curious, why are you passing the result of string comparison to a toggle ? [Toggle](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) expect two optional parameters: duration and complete callback function. In case if you don't need to speed up or do something afterwards you just toggle it as is.

> With no parameters, the .toggle() method simply toggles the visibility
> of elements

Comment: Does it become an issue to use toggle() without parameters? For now, all I need is to show elements that match and hide those that don't match. `toLowerCase()` was the missing puzzle piece!

Comment: No issues to use toggle without parameters, in docs they are optional which means that you can skip them. But it will affect animation speed if you pass value of indexOf result to toggle. Like 1 ms animation looks very fast ) But its your call how to use it @3141592653

Answer (score 0):

It was enough for me to simply use `toLowerCase()` for both the searchable elements and the user input, to compare the lower case values of both.

```
$("#search_input").keyup(function() {
  var value = this.value.toLowerCase();
  $("#table").find(".table_row").each(function(index) {
    if (!index) return;
    var id = $(this).find(".column-namelist").first().text();
    $(this).toggle(id.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) !== -1);
  });
});
```